# malloc unable to assign memory + doesnt warn

Tags: c

```
  char *str=NULL;
  strsave(s,str,n+1);
  printf("%s",str-n);
```

when I gdb debug this code I find that the str value is 0x0 which is null and also that my code is not catching this failed memory allocation , it doesnt execute str==NULL perror code ...Any idea

```
 void strsave(char *s,char *str,int n)
 {
    str=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* n);
            if(str==NULL)
                    perror("failed to allocate memory");
    while(*s)
    {
            *str++=*s++;
    }
            *str='\0';
 }
```

Comment: you can't just do `str=...` in C, you need to do `*str =...` and make `str` a double pointer `char **str`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you are assigning a pointer to the allocated memory to the **copy** of `str`. `str` inside the function is a local variable and it's located at a different memory address than the variable you are passing to `strsave` during the call.

In order to change the location that `str` is pointing at you need to pass a pointer to pointer to char in order to fix this.

```
void strsave(char *s,char **str,int n)
```

Another option would be to return a pointer to the newly allocated string.

However, the best solution would be to allocate memory **before** calling `strsave` and pass a valid pointer to `strsave`. It's easier to keep track of your memory allocations when the same module/layer or a function is responsible for both allocation and deallocation of a particular resource.

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard about parameters passing by value in C? If not - you should.

Anyway, allocating a memory without assigning its pointer to a variable (or assigning and then "leaking", as in your case) - strictly speaking is not an error. Yes, it's not a good practice, it's a resource/memory leak. But in some cases this may be what is really intended by the programmer.

From the compiler's point of view calling a function without assigning its return value to a variable is ok.